# UNQ_INDEX_PROCESS_INDEXER_CODE

Tags: mysql, url, index

a few time per day i get the following error (as listed in the reports)

```
a:5:{i:0;s:124:"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'catalog_url' for key 'UNQ_INDEX_PROCESS_INDEXER_CODE'";i:1;s:1900:"#0 /path-to-magento/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /path-to-magento/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /path-to-magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /path-to-magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `in...', Array)
#4 /path-to-magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `in...', Array)
#5 /path-to-magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(1998): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `in...', Array)
#6 /path-to-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Setup.php(82): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->insertArray('index_process', Array, Array)
#7 /path-to-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Setup.php(45): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Setup->_syncIndexes()
#8 /path-to-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#9 /path-to-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#10 /path-to-magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#11 /path-to-magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 /path-to-magento/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}";s:3:"url";s:98:"/accessoires/peuter_80_98.html";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

I have magento 1.8.1 CE.
Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the stack trace, Magento is trying to add the indexer **catalog_url** to the database for some reason.

I think this function is the key to finding out what might be wrong:

```
// Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Setup
protected function _syncIndexes()
{
    $connection = $this->getConnection();
    if (!$connection) {
        return $this;
    }
    $indexes = Mage::getConfig()->getNode(Mage_Index_Model_Process::XML_PATH_INDEXER_DATA);
    $indexCodes = array();
    foreach ($indexes->children() as $code => $index) {
        $indexCodes[] = $code;
    }
    $table = $this->getTable('index/process');
    $select = $connection->select()->from($table, 'indexer_code');
    $existingIndexes = $connection->fetchCol($select);
    $delete = array_diff($existingIndexes, $indexCodes);
    $insert = array_diff($indexCodes, $existingIndexes);

    if (!empty($delete)) {
        $connection->delete($table, $connection->quoteInto('indexer_code IN (?)', $delete));
    }
    if (!empty($insert)) {
        $insertData = array();
        foreach ($insert as $code) {
            $insertData[] = array(
                'indexer_code' => $code,
                'status' => Mage_Index_Model_Process::STATUS_REQUIRE_REINDEX
            );
        }
        if (method_exists($connection, 'insertArray')) {
            $connection->insertArray($table, array('indexer_code', 'status'), $insertData);
        }
    }
}
```

Magento goes through the setup procedure of the **Mage_Index** module. This is where new indexers get added and old ones are deleted, etc. That's what you can see in the code above.

In your case, the indexer **catalog_url** isn't found, so Magento tries to add it again.

Take a look at the table **index_process** in your database. It will probably have an entry for **catalog_url**. So, when Magento tries to insert a new entry for this indexer, you will get the constraint violation.

Comment: Hi, in what file should I place this code?

Comment: This is part of the Magento core. You will find it here: app\code\core\Mage\Index\Model\Resource\Setup.php

Comment: Thanks. Is this safe to use in a live environment or only in a developer environment?

Comment: This code is part of the core, so it is safe to use. However, you should debug the problem in a development environment.

Comment: The problem was in the need of reindexing the flat catalog category. But this was disabled and only visible in the database